# How can I change the position of a particular item in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to change an item's index position in an array, but I cannot figure out a way.

```
{
   "items": [
        1,
        3,
        2
   ]  
}
```

Comment: Which index you want to change???

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: I would like the array to be changed to  ```"items":[1, 2, 3]```

Comment: Parse this Json and get array and change the index as you want.

Comment: But how do I change the index is the question...

Comment: Why don't you just swap the two values?

Comment: @SalmanA You can't solve a move with a swap when the array is bigger.

Comment: @dystroy yes, but (in this question) OP seems to be concerned about just 2 values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to move an element in an array:

```
var arr = [
        1,
        3,
        2
   ];
var oldIndex = 2,
    newIndex = 1;


arr.splice(newIndex, 0, arr.splice(oldIndex, 1)[0]);
```

This makes `[1, 2, 3]`

The internal splice removes and returns the element, while the external one inserts it back.

---

Just for fun I defined a generic function able to move a slice, not just an element, and doing the computation of the index:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "move", {
    value:function(oldIndex, newIndex, nbElements){
        this.splice.apply(
            this, [newIndex-nbElements*(newIndex>oldIndex), 0].concat(this.splice(oldIndex, nbElements))
        );
    }
});

var arr = [0, 1, 2, 7, 8, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9];
arr.move(5, 3, 4);
console.log('1:', arr) // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] 

var arr = [0, 1, 2, 7, 8, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9];
arr.move(3, 9, 2);
console.log('2:', arr); // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] 

var arr = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 6, 7];
arr.move(5, 3, 1);
console.log('3:', arr); // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] 

var arr = [0, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7];
arr.move(1, 4, 1);
console.log('3:', arr); // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/wojazubasi/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: How does this work exactly? Why is there a ```splice``` within a ```splice```?

Comment: I really like the generic function! :P

Comment: @MichaelWilson2013 I've seen your edit. Isn't this clearer : http://jsbin.com/wojazubasi/1/edit?js,console,output ?

Comment: Yes that is a lot clearer, thanks for your help on this! Although if we lost the  output: http://jsbin.com/wojazubasi/1/edit?js,console

Answer (score -1):

If you want to sort them in Unicode order (where numbers become strings) you can use [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function.

```
items.sort();
```

If you have your custom order, you need to provide a sort function to the sort function.

```
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a is less than b by some ordering criterion) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a is greater than b by the ordering criterion) {
    return 1;
  }
  // a must be equal to b
  return 0;
}
```

and you use it like this:

```
items.sort(compare(a, b));
```

Comment: I would like to be able to change an items index, not sort them via their value.

Comment: @MichaelWilson2013 I'm not sure I understood: you want something like `sort()`, but that works on index and not on value?